# Jquerymobile how to get tap() to handle when link created pageinit()

Tags: jquery-mobile

i can't get the native tap() handler to fire with my link added after pageinit()

```
$('#feed div[data-role="content"]' ).append('<a id="dfd" data-rel="dialog" href="www.google.com" class="tr">&nbsp;</a>');
```

I've also tried making my own handler but no luck also:

```
$('#dfd').live("tap", function() {
 //JQM
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had some similar error, I dynamically created a list and wanted to catch clicking a list element. I dont know the problem, but the solution which worked for me was in JQ1.7 to use on('tap', 'li'..), in JQ 1.6.4 I had to use delegate(). Try delegate instead of live. If it does not help, try to use the delegate at the end of the append function, before refreshing the style.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

don't use .live() | deprecated

use .on('tap', elem) on a parent that will always be there